# how to install PIL for python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

please tell me how to install the PIL library for python 3.3. 
on the official website are installing only for version 2.x. but about the 3.x version says

> "A version for 3.X will be released later."

Comment: Short anwser - use [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pillow, a modern fork of PIL. This seems to work for people more often than installing straight PIL.

Look here for more info: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

And for 64bit binaries(and 32bit), for python 3.x, look here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow